# Cannot find existing module node js on linux centos

Tags: node.js, linux, centos

I get the following error message telling me that my custom class module cannot be found:

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './MyModule'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/centos/folder/server/foo/bar.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

Here is my bar.js file first line:

```
const MyModule = require('./MyModule');
```

My mymodule.js file is in the same folder as bar.js and contains the line `module.exports = MyModule` at the end.

What is also weird is that everything works properly on windows but when I try to run my project on a linux centos I get the error I previously described.

Comment: Try to rename `mymodule.js` to `MyModule.js`

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick, something must be not case sensitive on windows which would explain the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to rename the file  `mymodule.js` to `MyModule.js`. Windows is not case sensitive to filenames but UNIX/Linux is.